# Timer job at web application level

Tags: timer-jobs, web-application

I wanted to know that why Timer job is deployed at web application level only

Comment: You can timer jobs on farm, server, content database or web application scope. What are you trying to achieve or what is your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the SharePoint timer job utilizes SP Timer services under the services on server.

To access this it requires to be deployed at farm level as site and web level features cannot access the SPTimer service object.

Hope this helps

Thanks, 
Happy Coding.